# trouble accessing a class object from different class in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a class EncryptionUtilities.cs in Project.UI.Web -- App_Code.
And I am trying to access one of its method in Project.UI.Web ---Content---controls---admin----mycontrol.ascx. But I am unable to use it in              "using Project.UI.Web".I have also tried Project.UI.Web.Encryptionutilities.method(). It wasn't working. Can someone please help me how to resolve this. If needed, how to add references??

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is how the EncryptionUtilities method() is scoped. The actual answer here has some dependencies on version, but you should have it scoped either public or internal to allow other classes in the project. It could also be that the project will not compile, so the Intellisense is not picking it up. If so, solve that first, then make sure the method is scoped properly.